# Divs display on top of each other in fixed div

Tags: html, css

I am having issues making items side by side in a `fixed` div. I thought that I could set the items to `relative` and they would display side by side, but that doesn't work.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wkmukv6/

I have this **HTML**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="feed-tab"></div>
    <div class="feed-tab"></div>
    <div class="feed-tab"></div>
</div>
```

And this **CSS**

```
.tabs{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
}
.feed-tab{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

But what is happening, is that that `.feed-tab` div's are sitting on top of each other. what can I do to make them sit side by side?

Comment: Is putting the tabs in a table an option?

Comment: it is happening because all the 3 feed-tab ends up having the same position property. hence on top of each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First at all you are using `height:1px` on the container and negative `margin-top` on child elements. Why I don't know.

But make `relative` doesn't mean the elements will be side by side instead you need to change the `display` property or use `float`:

> display:inline-block

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/8wkmukv6/4/

or

> float:left // float:right

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/8wkmukv6/3/

Comment: I am using the 1px because the div will then cover up the background links making them non-clickable (if I am not mistaken), as these tabs are overlays, like facebook/google chat. The inline-block version works, but for some reason on my page it doesn't float them to the right properly...

Comment: The `margin-top: -200px` is messing up the items when I float them left... but as my prev comment the 1px is there for making the div small...

Comment: Ok if you want to keep the `1px` height then use `top` to offset insetad of margin-top... Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8wkmukv6/7/ @RyanNaddy

Comment: I can actually get rid of it with `pointer-events: none;` on the `.tabs` and `pointer-events: all;` on the `.feed-tab` which solves the problem with the `1px` div! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

CSS: Create a class "horizontal". For every child, display as inline.

```
.horizontal * {
  display: inline;
}
```

HTML: Wrap any elements in class "horizontal", they will appear side by side.

```
<div class="horizontal">
  <b>Bold</b>
  <u>Underline</u>
  <i>Italic</i>
</div>
```